# Can't connect to vmware cluster with powershell

Tags: powershell, vmware

I need to get stats from a cluster, like memory or cpu usage.
I'm trying to connect with a Connect-VIServer command, but can't get through it.
I have access to the vcenter with vSphere client without any problem.

```
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

Connect-VIServer -server 'ServerIP' -user 'Username' -password 'Password'
$clusterName = 'ServerIP'



$stat = 'cpu.usagemhz.average','mem.usage.average'

$entity = Get-Cluster -Name $clusterName

$start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)



Get-Stat -Entity $clusterName -Stat $stat -Start $start |

Group-Object -Property Timestamp |

Sort-Object -Property Name |

Select @{N='Cluster';E={$entity.Name}},

    @{N='Time';E={$_.Group[0].Timestamp}},

    @{N='CPU GHz Capacity';E={$script:capacity = [int]($entity.ExtensionData.Summary.TotalCPU/1000); $script:capacity}},

    @{N='CPU GHz Used';E={$script:used = [int](($_.Group | where{$_.MetricId -eq 'cpu.usagemhz.average'} | select -ExpandProperty Value)/1000); $script:used}},

    @{N='CPU % Free';E={[int](100 - $script:used/$script:capacity*100)}},

    @{N='Mem Capacity GB';E={$script:mcapacity = [int]($entity.ExtensionData.Summary.TotalMemory/1GB); $script:mcapacity}},

    @{N='Mem Used GB';E={$script:mused = [int](($_.Group | where{$_.MetricId -eq 'mem.usage.average'} | select -ExpandProperty Value) * $script:mcapacity/100); $script:mused}},

    @{N='Mem % Free';E={[int](100 - $script:mused/$script:mcapacity*100)}} |

Export-csv -Path C:\cluster-stats.csv
```

The script runs for several minutes but in the end all I get is an error that says :

```
Connect-VIServer : 25/10/2018 12:54:46    Connect-VIServer        The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.    
At line:3 char:1
+ Connect-VIServer -server 'ServerIP' -user 'Username' -password 'Password'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-VIServer], ViError
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_ConnectivityServiceImpl_Reconnect_WebException,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.ConnectVIServer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also specify 'https' as the protocol under:

```
Connect-ViServer
```

So something like:

```
Connect-ViServer -Server $myServer -Protocol https -Credential $myCreds
```

I have had issues like this before (has to do with SSL/TLS).. There have been a couple of differences in the ultimate fix, so one of these should help:

::Mainly for vCloud::

```
 function Set-VmWareTls
    {
        try {        
            # Grab current ciphers, convert their names to strings, add to an array
            $esp = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol.ToString().Split(',') | Foreach-Object {     
                $($_.TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' '))         
            }     
            # See if gathered ciphers contains the needed ciphers for vCloud/vCenter to connect without issue
            if (($esp -notcontains 'Tls11') -or ($esp -notcontains 'Tls12')) {     
                # if they're not found, add them
                [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;                     
            }        
            # if we were able to process evertying above, return true
            $true    
        } catch {    
            # If we are unable to set the ciphers return false
            $false    
        }     
    }
```

::vCenter::

```
function Set-IgnoreCertCheck
{
    if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'ServerCertificateValidationCallback').Type)
    {
        $certCallback = @"
            using System;
            using System.Net;
            using System.Net.Security;
            using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
            public class ServerCertificateValidationCallback
            {
                public static void Ignore()
                {
                    if(ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback ==null)
                    {
                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                            delegate
                            (
                                Object obj, 
                                X509Certificate certificate, 
                                X509Chain chain, 
                                SslPolicyErrors errors
                            )
                            {
                                return true;
                            };
                    }
                }
            }
"@

    Add-Type $certCallback
    }
    [ServerCertificateValidationCallback]::Ignore()
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're doing it that way instead of: `Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore`?

Comment: Nope - I simply was not aware of that. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can do.

First, upgrade your version of PowerCLI. PowerCLI hasn't used PowerShell snapins for a couple years (~2015) and probably won't work on vSphere 6.0 and newer.

Second, use a function by the name of `Resolve-Error`. This will recall the last error object and output a property that contains some additional information which may help you further troubleshoot.

```
function Resolve-Error ($ErrorRecord=$Error[0])
{
   $ErrorRecord | Format-List * -Force
   $ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo | Format-List *
   $Exception = $ErrorRecord.Exception
   for ($i = 0; $Exception; $i++, ($Exception = $Exception.InnerException))
   {   “$i” * 80
       $Exception | Format-List * -Force
   }
}
```

Run the above lines of code, run your script again, then run `Resolve-Error`. If the output doesn't make sense, copy/paste it here.

Comment: It gives me 2 errors but I can't understand where it went wrong :
     - Connect-VIServer        The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
    - Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.